# Append content of one file to another file without loosing formatting

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have several files in .txt format. My goal is to unify the content of all these files into a source file (also .txt format) without changing the formatting. To start, I just want to copy the content from one file to another.

The following code snip allows to copy the content. However, I lose the formatting.

```
%   load destination file in append mode
destFileId = fopen(destFile, "a");
%   load source file in read mode
sourceFileId = fopen(sourceFile, "r");

%   Extract content from source file
content = textscan(sourceFileId, '%c');

%   Append content into destination file
fprintf(destFileId, content{:});

%   Close both files
fclose(destFileId);
fclose(sourceFileId);
```

Comment: What kind of formatting?

Comment: What do you mean by "I lose formatting"? Anyhow, you either should know the formatting of your file (e.g. because it's a log file you wrote), and set `fprintf` to the same format, or use some kind of text processing tool (read: `regexp` voodoo) to find out which formatting has been used and use that to write as well.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself specific enough. The file contains some continuous text without a pattern. I loose all the whitespace characters (space, new line, etc.) when I copy the file to the destination file. They should be copied as well.

Comment: If you are on Linux or MacOS, you can do this from within MATLAB with `!cat src1.txt src2.txt > dest.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However, my final goal is to copy several files from multiple subfolders into one document. Thus, I decided to use a language with a higher level than bash.

Comment: To add to Cris Luengo's comment, you can also do this on windows with `system` : `system('copy 1.txt+2.txt+3.txt Output.txt')`

Comment: @Caduceus how come you are not specifying the conversion character `'%c'` when using fprintf ?

Comment: @pkpkpk I agree it is cleaner with '%c'. However, it does not change anything in the output.

Comment: @Caduceus : please tag me when replying (`@Cris`) so I get notified. I’m not suggesting you use Bash. You can generate a shell command in MATLAB and run it from within MATLAB. It’s easy to fill in different file names in that command programmatically.

Comment: I think using [`fileread`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) instead of `textscan` will help in preserving formattiing as you wish to (`fileread` reads whole file content as a simple matlab string, preserving for whitespaces and newlines)

Comment: @CitizenInsane That one is new to me! I would have suggested `fread`, but your solution is clearly the better one.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks Cris, i turned my comment into an answer, i haven't tested the code but I think it should be ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using [`fileread`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) instead of `textscan` will help in preserving formattiing as you wish to (`fileread` reads whole file content as a simple matlab string, preserving both for whitespaces and newlines)

Here is some pseudo code (not tested):

```
 function [] = Dummy(desFile, sourcesFiles)
 %[
    % Open destination file for writing (discarding previous content)
    [destFileId, msg] = fopen(destFile, 'w');
    if (desFileId < 0), error(msg); end

    % Make sure to close file on any error, ctrl+c (and normal termination of course)
    cuo = onCleanup(@()fclose(destFileId));

    % Copy file contents to destination
    count = length(sourcesFiles);
    for fi = 1:count,

        text = fileread(sourcesFiles{fi});
        fprintf(destFileId, '%s', text);

    end
 %]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `fprintf` to concatenate files is that if the file contains special characters (like `\` or `%`) then `fprintf` will likely fail. A very similar approach would be to use `fread` and `fwrite` to directly concatenate the file contents without interpreting them in any way.

```
function catfiles(dest, sources)
    fdest = fopen(dest, 'wb');

    for source = 1:numel(sources)
        fsource = fopen(source,'rb');
        source_data = fread(fsource);
        fwrite(fdest, source_data);
        fclose(fsource);
    end

    fclose(fdest);
```

---

*Usage*

```
>> catfiles('dest.txt', {'source1.txt', 'source2.txt'});
```

---

I didn't include all the checks that @CitizenInsane's answer does but they are a good idea.